# How to set language change key button from iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

[I want this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0lbw.jpg)but I get [my outout photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSO5y.png)I try to set language icon but no display in my keyboard.

messageTextField.keyboardType= UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;

Comment: I unable to understand your ?, pease add some info.

Comment: see my 1st photos want this icon but no in my keyboard, check 2nd photo

Comment: does your app support at least the two languages which you want the keyboard to be visible for?

Comment: @SaravanaGanesh - change your messageTextField.keyboardType= UIKeyboardTypeDefault; and try once

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TextField.keyboardType= UIKeyboardTypeDefault;